# Copy data from hdfs to s3 using sys.process._

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark

I need to copy files from hdfs to s3 using below command in a spark job
I am using the below steps, but I get below error, what am I missing:

```
import sys.process._
"s3-dist-cp --src  /user/data-store/ --dest s3:/parquet2/ --s3ServerSideEncryption --groupBy='.*(.parquet).*'".!


17/08/09 07:56:00 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Running with args: -libjars /usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/guava-15.0.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/s3-dist-cp-2.5.0.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/s3-dist-cp.jar --src hdfs:///user/data-store/session/country=us/traffic/dt=2016-01-03/ --dest s3://digitas-dct-qa/development/vendors/comscore/clean/analytical-data/sessions-sad/temp4/country=us/traffic/dt=2016-01-03/parquet4/ --s3ServerSideEncryption --groupBy='.*(.parquet).*'
17/08/09 07:56:01 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: S3DistCp args: --src hdfs:///user/data-store/session/country=us/traffic/dt=2016-01-03/ --dest s3://digitas-dct-qa/development/vendors/comscore/clean/analytical-data/sessions-sad/temp4/country=us/traffic/dt=2016-01-03/parquet4/ --s3ServerSideEncryption --groupBy='.*(.parquet).*'
17/08/09 07:56:01 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Using output path 'hdfs:/tmp/2581fcfc-c4fd-485a-9159-f34e7392cafa/output'
17/08/09 07:56:01 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone result: us-east-1a
17/08/09 07:56:02 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Created 0 files to copy 0 files
17/08/09 07:56:04 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Reducer number: 31
17/08/09 07:56:05 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://ip-10-1-55-195.ec2.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
17/08/09 07:56:05 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-10-1-55-195.ec2.internal/10.1.55.195:8032
17/08/09 07:56:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1502254855242_0014
17/08/09 07:56:05 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Try to recursively delete hdfs:/tmp/2581fcfc-c4fd-485a-9159-f34e7392cafa/tempspace
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running job
        at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:927)
        at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.Main.main(Main.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://ip-10-1-55-195.ec2.internal:8020/tmp/2581fcfc-c4fd-485a-9159-f34e7392cafa/files
```

Comment: Input path does not exist: hdfs://ip-10-1-55-195.ec2.internal:8020/tmp/2581fcfc-c4fd-485a-9159-f34e7392cafa/files

Comment: That should not matter, think hdfs is trying to write to a temp location to group by files, but that temp location is not available from sys.process